# Apache download php code instead of executing it in aws server (laravel web apps)

Tags: php, laravel, apache, amazon-web-services

I have made configuration on /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf to allow .htaccess

> AllowOverride None  => AllowOverride All

This is my .htacess file in my /var/www/html/

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ abc/public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This is my .htaccess file in /var/www/html/abc/public

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /abc/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

When i am opening xxxxxxx.com, it will redirect me to public directories.

> /var/www/html/abc/public

It will display all the folder inside public but does not execute the index.php inside the public folder.

When i tried to acess the login page by xxxxxx.com/login, it prompted me to download the index.php file.
[image]

When i tried to open a php file, it doesn't execute the code. It is displaying the code as text instead of execute it.

How can i solve this issue? I have no idea what's wrong is going on, appreciate if someone might help me out. Thanks.

Comment: Did you remember to install php on the server?

Comment: @MauranMuthiah Yes, it shows php version 5.5.6 when i execute php -v to see the version of php.

Comment: Having PHP available on the command line does not guarantee anything about Apache bindings.

Comment: @mario How can i know what caused this issue?

Comment: Look at the log files, Apache config files, and foremost the linked duplicate and similar questions.

Comment: In my modules folder, i can't found the php5 module.so is that caused this issue?